# Java regex for replacing all special characters except underscore

Tags: java, regex

I would like a regular expression for removing all special characters except an underscore. I can replace all special characters, but I don't know how to keep the underscores. Here's the code for removing all speial characters,

```
String myname= "!john_smith@#-".replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "");
```

Any ideas how to modify the regex so that I keep underscores?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well `\\p...` is the same as `[^\\P...]` (negated character class of characters **not** having the property), and then you could put the underscore in there as well:

```
"[^\\P{Punct}_]+"
```

Alternatively, use a negative lookahead

```
"(?:(?!_)\\p{Punct})+"
```

Also, seeing your example, maybe something as simple as this will be enough for you:

```
"[^\\w\\s]+"
```

Will remove everything except for letters, digits, underscores and whitespace.

Comment: +1 you would deserve more credit for having fixed everybody else's answers!

Comment: @assylias :D thank you. I just realized that I had to fix my own ^^

Answer (score 7):

Use set difference:

```
System.out.println("#%a#%^$^_#$%b#$".replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^_]]", ""));
```

prints

```
a_b
```

Reference: [Character Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)